# Setting a env variable to point a file path

Tags: php, laravel, dialogflow-es

I am trying to integrate Dialogflow API with my **Laravel application**. I need to set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in the env file to point to the location of the service account JSON file.

I am doing this -

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/dialogflow_key.json
```

but this only returns a string and not the actual location of the key.
How do I properly set the JSON file?

Comment: The env is usually set on os level. Reading from your tags, it looks like you are actuating on web level. To influence the webservers machine env from within php, I see 2 options. Use the php's function [putenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) or use a php lib like [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: You can read the [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) too.

Comment: Thank you, you just saved me

Comment: you are welcome, I would appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The env is usually set on os level. Reading from your tags, it looks like you are actuating on web level. To influence the webserver's machine env from within `php`, I would go for one of these two options:

1. Use the php's function [putenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)
2. use a php lib like [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php/blob/master/README.md)

A likely third option could be to go for a specific laravel lib that supports google auth: [laravel-google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage/blob/master/README.md).
They have a sample in there which makes use of [putenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php)

For general information you can have a look on the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).